# ERB/Templating clue for ruby

Tags: ruby, erb, template-engine

Optimally I'd want template to look something like this:

```
interfaces {
  <%= name %> {
    description "<%= description %>";
    mtu <%= mtu %>;
  }
}
```

However, I'd want lines not to be printed if the code evaluates to non-true value. It could be hack to ERB, where after \n it sets print_line = true and after evaluating code with b%> to false it sets print_line = false, and only print if print_line.
But it seems changing ERB for this isn't exactly trivial, it reads whole template, non-code parts are inserted as print "data", and result is single big string of ruby code which is evaluated as whole during #result. I would either need to eval b%> code during string-scanning and just insert print "data" if it returns true, or nothing at all or I'd need to rescan the code in #result to run b%> first.

It seems bit fruitless to even use template, if you end up writing all of it inside code blocks, like:

```
interfaces {
  <%= name %> {
    <% if description %>
    description "<%= description %>";
    <% end%>
    <% if mtu %>
    mtu <%= mtu%>;
    <% end%>
  }
}
```

or:

```
interfaces {
  <%= name %> {
    <%= "description \"#{description}\";" if description %>
    <%= "mtu #{mtu};" if mtu %>
  }
}
```

I need to support various different configuration formats, in some other configuration format it might be 'maximum-transfer-unit <%= mtu> bytes'. I wish to keep all platform-specific intelligence in the template and actual code in the template minimum. I have no problem adding platform agnostic complexity outside the templates.

Seems like relatively common use-case. Before I go NIHing my own template language or hacking ERB, are there perhaps some other template language better fit for my use-case. Or missingsomething else?

I've implemented the hack for <%b stuff %> where whole line is omitted if that evaluates to false. ERB was not designed for anything like this at all so it's very dirty, and it may be better for me to just write my own template language, unless someone can suggest maybe existing solution where I can cleanly implement something like.
For interested parties, hack is here http://p.ip.fi/-NeJ

Ended up re-inventing the wheel: https://github.com/ytti/malline

Comment: Could you simply pass in array of names and values, and loop over it?

Comment: @NeilSlater not really. Lets assume 'description' and 'mtu' are keys, and description and mtu are their values. I get from model only the values, I don't get the keys. I need to generate the configuration for various platform, others refer to these values with different keys. I guess I could do in template something like %w(description mtu).each{|key|val=eval(key);puts #{key} #{value} if val}. But again, it's not really templating. Maybe I could hack ERB to set 'print_line = true' after it sees \n, and set 'print_line = false' after block with b%> evals false.

Comment: You already know the "keys", otherwise you wouldn't know to put them in the template. I'm suggesting rather than using those variable names in the template code, that you create a local array, in Ruby perhaps like this: `config_items = [ :description, :mtu ].map { |vname| vval = send( vname );  vval ? [ vname, vval ] : nil }.compact`  -although I'm not clear whether `self` is your model, or whether you are loading the values to other local variables in the Ruby already?

Comment: What I mean, I may need to refer in some other platform mtu as say 'maximum-transfer-unit <%= mtu > bytes', so i only know value is inside 'mtu', I do not know they key, in this case 'maximum-transfer-unit. So any magic suggestion to iterate, implies I know both, for each platform. The reason for the template is, that the keys are in the config statically, I just fill them in with values. self is my model (it's subclassed from sequel).

Comment: OK, I think you would need to resolve such mapping outside of the template for an array to be useful. To be clear, you have data describing config with standardised labels, and you want to place them into a config file, potentially under another name, only if the value exists in the data. And you want to resolve both the mapping (to config-specific keys) and existence or not in the template code? You know how to do this at least one way, but think the template code necessary is too verbose?

Comment: @NeilSlater exactly. In perfect world I'd use the first example, which magically omits printing the whole line, if the embedded code evaluates to nil.

Answer (score 2):

#### Helper methods

```
def description_helper(description)
  "description \"#{description}\";" if description
end
def mtu_helper(mtu)
  "mtu #{mtu};" if mtu
end

interfaces {
  <%= name %> {
    <%= description_helper %>
    <%= mtu_helper %>
  }
}
```

---

#### [Decorator pattern](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in)

```
class MyObject
  def description
    'some description'
  end
  def mtu
    nil
  end
  module ViewDecorator
    def description
      "description \"#{super}\";" if super
    end
    def mtu
      "mtu #{super};" if super
    end
  end
end

o = MyObject.new
p o.description #=> "some description"
p o.mtu #=> nil
o.extend MyObject::ViewDecorator
p o.description #=> "description \"some description\";"
p o.mtu #=> nil
```

Comment: Here platform specific code in the helper or decorator, which makes the point for template quite moot, I might as well use string/heredoc etc. I really want to keep platform specific intelligence only in template. It might be my only solution is to NIH new template language, or patch ERB with %b>.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood; my answer clearly doesn't fit with your problem. I suggest you to update your question with these additional informations (I read the discussion with @NeilSlater too), because a user who read it can be misleaded IMHO